# How to return QTextEdit RichText as plain text?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTextEdit` whose textFormat is `Qt::RichText` so it is possible to format the text with HTML tags. On this `QTextEdit` I have a `QPopupMenu` thats filled with `QActions`. One of these actions is a simple copy that connects into `SLOT( onClipboardCopy() )`.
`QTextEdit`'s copy() is defined as "Copies any selected text (from selection 0) to the clipboard."
If there is something selected this function is perfect. However, I'd like to copy ALL of the TextEdit's content when nothing is selected.
Here's the slot:

```
void WidgetName::onClipboardCopy()
{

    if ( TextEdit->hasSelectedText() )
    {
        TextEdit->copy();
    }
    else
    {
        QClipboard * xClipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
        xClipboard->setText( TextEdit->text() );
    }
}
```

The problem is in else TextEdit->text() returns the text with all of it's HTML tags. Is there an easy way to discard them?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I realized that I could select the text before copying. I get the desired effect by changing the code to:

```
void WidgetName::onClipboardCopy()
{

    if ( TextEdit->hasSelectedText() )
    {
        TextEdit->copy();
    }
    else
    {
        TextEdit->selectAll();
        TextEdit->copy();
        TextEdit->removeSelection();

        //QClipboard * xClipboard = QApplication::clipboard();      
        //xClipboard->setText( TextEdit->text() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't [`toPlainText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#toPlainText) work?

Comment: I guess it could, however I'm working in an old version of Qt that doesn't have toPlainText(). Wish I could convince my boss to update. I see so much functionality in newer versions that I could use but he has this "if it works, don't change it" mindset that drives me crazy. I got to make a lot of workarounds and write code that's already been written... Futhermore, I ask stupid questions here that are already solved.

Comment: Concerning _I'm working in an old version of Qt that doesn't have toPlainText()._: That old? -> [plainText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop): _This property was introduced in Qt 4.3._

Comment: @Scheff'sCat `QTextEdit::toPlainText ()` was introduced even before (you can find it in Qt 4.1). Anyway, I suppose that he is using quite legacy Qt (like Qt3), since there is no QTextEdit::text() since version 4. QtextEdit::text() returns the text as plain text.

Comment: Exactly. Qt3. To be more precise, 3.3.8.